# Laravel 4.2 Eloquent fetch specific user and specific role

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

In the Laravel Eloquent many to many example the scenario of users and roles is being used http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many say I have a group of users with the same family "Simpson" name and I want to get all of them with the role of being "Engineer". How can I accomplish this using Eloquent? In the example the "has" method is used http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations but how do I go about querying the database for a value present in both the user table and the role table?

I am not looking for the

```
User::find(1)->roles();
```

I am looking for a way to do something like

```
User::whereFamilyName('simpson')->roles()->whereName('Engineer')
```

the 2nd whereName would the be querying the roles table and not the user table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get users that have particular role:

```
$role = 'Engineer';

// users with family name Simpson having role Engineer
$users = User::whereFamilyName('Simpson')
      ->whereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($role) {
           $q->where('roles.name', $role); // it joins the table so you may need to use prefixed column name, otherwise you can still use dynamic whereName()
      })
      // with('roles') if needed
      ->get();
// returns Collection of User models without roles or with all roles attached to each user if needed
```

Otherwise simply join the tables:

```
User::whereFamilyName('Simpson')
   ->join('role_user', 'role_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
   ->join('roles', 'role_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
   ->whereName('Engineer') // again columns name conflict may occur
   ->get(['users.*']);
```

All values hardcoded here to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks deczo, how do I pass a parameter into the closure function in the first example? Engineer could be "Bartender" instead.

Comment: +1 for using `whereHas`. Many people want it, but misuse it using `with`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$users = User::with(array('roles' => function($query){
    $query->whereName('Engineer');
}))->whereFamilyName('simpson')->get(); // whereFamilyName = family_name in DB
```

Hope you have declared the relationship properly and also make sure whether it's `roles` or `role` in the `User` model for relationship with `roles` table. I've used `roles` because you have used it in your question's code.

Comment: This will only filter the roles object, not the main result. You should use `whereHas` instead.